# Amazon ECS stuck on preparing service 1 of 9

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am using Amazon ECS for the first time so I'm 90% sure my problem is likely user error in some capacity.

The problem I am running into is that, when I go through the Getting Started wizard, the launch process seems to hang on "preparing service 1 of 9". Per the screenshot below, it seems like the cluster is created and everything else is in a pending state. No amount of time seems to allow the process to complete.

How can I find out why this is happening?

[image: ECS Launch Status]

Comment: How long have you waited? I've never used that "getting started" thing before. It's strange that it would create the cluster before creating the VPC and subnets.

Comment: @MarkB - I've made several attempts and even waited hours for one of them to complete.

Comment: Unfortunately I think that wizard is outdated and apparently has some issues at this point. I would recommend using one of the many other methods of deploying to ECS, such as AWS CoPilot, Docker Desktop ECS support, CloudFormation, AWS CDK, or Terraform for example.

Comment: Thanks @MarkB. Of the solutions you have provided, which is the most efficient for a solo developer to use?

Comment: I don't think any of them are less efficient for solo versus team of developers. I think the efficiency depends entirely on your level of experience. Docker Desktop ECS support is probably the easiest to use, but it ultimately uses CloudFormation (which I personally dislike) so it's hard to recommend. I use Terraform myself with both single developer hobby projects, as well as large corporate projects.